# how to change the ninja command parameter

Tags: macos, chromium, ninja

Now I am using this command to build chrome:

```
➜  src git:(64ca7395b4) autoninja -C out/Default chrome
ninja: Entering directory `out/Default'
[23/33973] OBJCXX obj/third_party/webrtc/modules/desktop_capture/desktop_capture_objc/screen_capturer_mac.o
FAILED: obj/third_party/webrtc/modules/desktop_capture/desktop_capture_objc/screen_capturer_mac.o
../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++ -MMD -MF obj/third_party/webrtc/modules/desktop_capture/desktop_capture_objc/screen_capturer_mac.o.d -DDCHECK_ALWAYS_ON=1 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -DCR_XCODE_VERSION=1430 -DCR_CLANG_REVISION=\"llvmorg-17-init-4759-g547e3456-2\" -DCOMPONENT_BUILD -DCR_LIBCXX_REVISION=049d48aa99786a2452537a5f5e3c411c741abb82 -D_LIBCPP_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=1 -D_DEBUG -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DWEBRTC_ENABLE_PROTOBUF=1 -DWEBRTC_STRICT_FIELD_TRIALS=0 -DRTC_ENABLE_VP9 -DRTC_DAV1D_IN_INTERNAL_DECODER_FACTORY -DWEBRTC_HAVE_SCTP -DENABLE_EXTERNAL_AUTH -DHAVE_WEBRTC_VIDEO -DLOGGING_INSIDE_WEBRTC -DWEBRTC_ARCH_ARM64 -DWEBRTC_HAS_NEON -DWEBRTC_LIBRARY_IMPL -DWEBRTC_ENABLE_SYMBOL_EXPORT -DWEBRTC_ENABLE_AVX2 -DWEBRTC_NON_STATIC_TRACE_EVENT_HANDLERS=0 -DWEBRTC_CHROMIUM_BUILD -DWEBRTC_POSIX -DWEBRTC_MAC -DABSL_ALLOCATOR_NOTHROW=1 -I../.. -Igen -I../../buildtools/third_party/libc++ -I../../third_party/webrtc_overrides -I../../third_party/webrtc -Igen/third_party/webrtc -I../../third_party/abseil-cpp -I../../third_party/perfetto/include -Igen/third_party/perfetto/build_config -Igen/third_party/perfetto -I../../third_party/libyuv/include -I../../third_party/webrtc/sdk/objc -I../../third_party/webrtc/sdk/objc/base  -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wextra-semi -Wunreachable-code-aggressive -Wthread-safety -Wunguarded-availability -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-psabi -Wloop-analysis -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wenum-compare-conditional -Wno-ignored-pragma-optimize -Wno-deprecated-builtins -Wno-bitfield-constant-conversion -Wno-deprecated-this-capture -Wshadow -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -fno-ident -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector-strong -fcolor-diagnostics -fmerge-all-constants -fcrash-diagnostics-dir=../../tools/clang/crashreports -mllvm -instcombine-lower-dbg-declare=0 -ffp-contract=off -fcomplete-member-pointers -arch arm64 -fno-global-isel -mno-outline -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -D__DATE__= -D__TIME__= -D__TIMESTAMP__= -ffile-compilation-dir=. -no-canonical-prefixes -ftrivial-auto-var-init=pattern -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g2 -gdwarf-aranges -Xclang -debug-info-kind=limited -isysroot ../../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk -mmacos-version-min=10.13 -fvisibility=hidden -Xclang -add-plugin -Xclang find-bad-constructs -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang raw-ref-template-as-trivial-member -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang check-stack-allocated -Wheader-hygiene -Wstring-conversion -Wtautological-overlap-compare -Wexit-time-destructors -Wglobal-constructors -Wno-shadow -Wctad-maybe-unsupported -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wstrict-overflow -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wobjc-missing-property-synthesis -Wno-undefined-bool-conversion -Wno-tautological-undefined-compare -std=c++20 -Wno-trigraphs -fobjc-call-cxx-cdtors -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -nostdinc++ -isystem../../buildtools/third_party/libc++/trunk/include -isystem../../buildtools/third_party/libc++abi/trunk/include -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fobjc-arc -c ../../third_party/webrtc/modules/desktop_capture/mac/screen_capturer_mac.mm -o obj/third_party/webrtc/modules/desktop_capture/desktop_capture_objc/screen_capturer_mac.o
```

I want to change the `-mmacos-version-min=10.13` to `-mmacos-version-min=13.0`. I have tried this:

```
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=13.0 && autoninja -C out/Default chrome
```

and this:

```
export macosx_deployment_target=13.0
autoninja -C out/Default chrome
```

and this:

```
autoninja -C out/Default chrome -mmacos-version-min=10.13
```

both did not work. what should I do to change the args? I also tried to add this config `mac_sdk_min = "13.0"` into `args.gn`, still could not work.

Comment: I have not tried this yet but maybe try modifying this file: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:build/config/mac/mac_sdk.gni;l=27?q=mac_deployment_target&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc or this one: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:build/config/mac/mac_sdk_overrides.gni